# What if the column to be indexed is nvarchar data type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, indexing

I retrieve data by joining multiple tables as indicated on the image below. On the other hand, as there is no data in the FK column (EmployeeID) of Event table, I have to use CardNo (nvarchar) fields in order to join the two tables. On the other hand, the digit numbers of CardNo fields in the Event and Employee tables are different, I also have to use RIGHT function of SQL Server and this makes the query to be executed approximately 10 times longer. So, in this scene what should I do? Can I use CardNo field without changing its data type to int, etc (because there are other problem might be seen after changing it and it sill be better to find a solution without changing the data type of it). Here is also execution plan of the query below.

**Query:**

```
; WITH a AS (SELECT emp.EmployeeName, emp.Status, dep.DeptName, job.JobName, emp.CardNo 
    FROM TEmployee emp 
    LEFT JOIN TDeptA AS dep ON emp.DeptAID = dep.DeptID 
    LEFT JOIN TJob AS job ON emp.JobID = job.JobID),                           

b AS (SELECT eve.EventID, eve.EventTime, eve.CardNo, evt.EventCH, dor.DoorName 
    FROM TEvent eve LEFT JOIN TEventType AS evt ON eve.EventType = evt.EventID
    LEFT JOIN TDoor AS dor ON eve.DoorID = dor.DoorID) 
    SELECT * FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON RIGHT(a.CardNo, 8) = RIGHT(b.CardNo, 8)

ORDER BY b.EventID ASC
```

[image: Join schema]

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? (That's another product...)

Comment: You could store the `RIGHT()` stuff in the database rather than calculating it on the fly every time. Since you didn't provide any data, I don't really know what this might look like though

Comment: The problem here isn't that the data being joined is varchar, it is that you are joining on a portion of it which requires you to wrap the column in a function. This renders the query nonSARGable and it has to calculate the right 8 characters for every single row which forces an index scan.

Comment: @JoePhilllips Thanks for reply. Do you meant CardNo with data? If so, here is the sample data as 00014293720, 00007004720, 00013145687, 00012597006. If you need another data or table result please inform me.

Comment: @SeanLange Any idea to solve it? Sorry, I have no so much experience and would be appreciated if you help. Thanks...

Comment: The absolute BEST way to solve would be to stop storing multiple pieces of information in a single value. This is almost always the case when you have to join on only a portion of a value. The second best option is what @JoePhilllips already suggested, put this portion of the information in a computed column.

Comment: Hm, I saw this picture yesterday. And the question was exactly about `RIGHT` in `WHERE`.

Comment: @Ivan Starostin Any solution suggestion?

Comment: Well, I remember some from previous discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks all of your help. With the help of your answers, I managed to reduce the query execution time from 2 minutes to 1 at the first step after using computed columns. After that, when creating an index for these columns, I managed to reduce the execution time to 3 seconds. Wow, it is really perfect :)

Here are the steps posted for those who suffers from a similar problem:

**Step I:** Adding computed columns to the tables (As CardNo fields are nvarchar data type, I specify data type of computed columns as int):

```
ALTER TABLE TEvent ADD CardNoRightEight AS RIGHT(CAST(CardNo AS int), 8)  
ALTER TABLE TEmployee ADD CardNoRightEight AS RIGHT(CAST(CardNo AS int), 8)
```

**Step II:** Create index for the computed columns in order to execute the query faster:

```
CREATE INDEX TEmployee_CardNoRightEight_IDX ON TEmployee (CardNoRightEight)
CREATE INDEX TEvent_CardNoRightEight_IDX ON TEvent (CardNoRightEight)
```

**Step 3:** Update the query by using the computed columns in it:

```
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT emp.EmployeeName, emp.Status, dep.DeptName, job.JobName, emp.CardNoRightEight --emp.CardNo 
    FROM TEmployee emp 
    LEFT JOIN TDeptA AS dep ON emp.DeptAID = dep.DeptID 
    LEFT JOIN TJob AS job ON emp.JobID = job.JobID
    ),                         
b AS (
    SELECT eve.EventID, eve.EventTime, evt.EventCH, dor.DoorName, eve.CardNoRightEight --eve.CardNo
    FROM TEvent eve 
    LEFT JOIN TEventType AS evt ON eve.EventType = evt.EventID 
    LEFT JOIN TDoor AS dor ON eve.DoorID = dor.DoorID) 

SELECT * FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON a.CardNoRightEight = b.CardNoRightEight --ON RIGHT(a.CardNo, 8) = RIGHT(b.CardNo, 8)
ORDER BY b.EventID ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a computed column to your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEmployee -- Don't start your table names with prefixes, you already know they're tables
ADD CardNoRight8 AS RIGHT(CardNo, 8) PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE TEvent
ADD CardNoRight8 AS RIGHT(CardNo, 8) PERSISTED

CREATE INDEX TEmployee_CardNoRight8_IDX ON TEmployee (CardNoRight8)
CREATE INDEX TEvent_CardNoRight8_IDX ON TEvent (CardNoRight8)
```

You don't need to persist the column since it already matches the criteria for a computed column to be indexed, but adding the `PERSISTED` keyword shouldn't hurt and might help the performance of other queries. It will cause a minor performance hit on updates and inserts, but that's probably fine in your case unless you're importing a lot of data (millions of rows) at a time.

The better solution though is to make sure that your columns that are supposed to match actually match. If the right 8 characters of the card number are something meaningful, then they shouldn't be part of the card number, they should be another column. If this is an issue where one table uses leading zeroes and the other doesn't then you should fix that data to be consistent instead of putting together work arounds like this.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Actually I tried it but there is an error during index creation : "Column 'CardNoRight8' in table 'TEmployee' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.". I think it is due to data type of CardNo or CardNoRight8 field. So, is it possible to define it during table altering above or later? If not, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try adding the `PERSISTED` keyword when you add the column. In my own tests it wasn't necessary, but without seeing your table structures there could be something that was missed.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I also posted the steps for those who suffers from a similar problem. Voted+

Comment: Please ask a new question so that others who run into that same issue can find it more easily then trying to stumble on our comments here. Comments aren't intended for extended discussions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line is what is costing you 86% of the query time:

```
LEFT JOIN a ON RIGHT(a.CardNo, 8) = RIGHT(b.CardNo, 8)
```

This is happening because it has to run `RIGHT()` on those fields for every row and then match them with the other table. This is obviously going to be inefficient.

The most straightforward solution is probably to either remove the `RIGHT()` entirely or else to re-implement it as a built-in column on the table so it doesn't have to be calculated on the fly while the query is running.

While inserting the record, you would have to also insert the eight, right digits of the card number and store it in this field. My original thought was to use a computed column but I don't think those can be indexed so you'd have to use a regular column.

```
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT emp.EmployeeName, emp.Status, dep.DeptName, job.JobName, emp.CardNoRightEight 
    FROM TEmployee emp 
    LEFT JOIN TDeptA AS dep ON emp.DeptAID = dep.DeptID 
    LEFT JOIN TJob AS job ON emp.JobID = job.JobID
),                           
b AS (
    SELECT eve.EventID, eve.EventTime, eve.CardNoRightEight, evt.EventCH, dor.DoorName 
    FROM TEvent eve LEFT JOIN TEventType AS evt ON eve.EventType = evt.EventID
    LEFT JOIN TDoor AS dor ON eve.DoorID = dor.DoorID
) 
SELECT *
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.CardNoRightEight = b.CardNoRightEight
ORDER BY b.EventID ASC
```

Comment: Actually I tried to remove RIGHT() for the first time, but after that it cannot compare card numbers properly and I had to use it. On the other hand, I have no idea how to implement CardNoRightEight? Could you please update your answer by explaining also that? Thanks..

Comment: There are some additional requirements for creating an index on a computed column, but in this case it will meet all of the requirements, so it should be fine.

Comment: `UPDATE TEmployee SET CardNoRightEight = RIGHT(CardNo, 8);
UPDATE TEvent SET CardNoRightEight = RIGHT(CardNo, 8);`

Comment: The computed columns was created but there is an error during index creation : "Column 'CardNoRight8' in table 'TEmployee' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.". I think it is due to data type of CardNo or CardNoRight8 field. So, is it possible to define it during table altering above or later? If not, how to fix this problem?

Comment: @hexadecimal What data type did you use? Use the smallest varchar that you need

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I also posted the steps for those who suffers from a similar problem. Voted+

Answer (score 0):

This will help you see how to add a calculated column to your database.

```
create table #temp (test varchar(30))
insert into #temp
values('000456')

alter table #temp
add test2 as right(test, 3) persisted

select * from #temp
```

The other alternative is to fix the data and the data entry so that both columns are the same data type and contain the same leading zeros (or remove them)

Comment: The computed columns was created but there is an error during index creation : "Column 'CardNoRight8' in table 'TEmployee' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.". I think it is due to data type of CardNo or CardNoRight8 field. So, is it possible to define it during table altering above or later? If not, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I also posted the steps for those who suffers from a similar problem. Voted+